# Vacuum packed fish

Tags: fish

I left several vacuum packed packages of salmon and ahi tuna filets in a cooler with ice bags in my car  are they still good after 24 hours.?please answer

Comment: are they still cool ?

Answer (score 2):

The "*24 hours*" time is irrelevant.

The only issue is the temperature of the meat at the time you rescued it.

If the bags are still frozen, it should be okay.

If not, but the meat still feels very cold, it's probably okay.

But if the meat is warmer (over 4°C), you have no idea how long it has been warm enough for bacteria to grow, so don't take a chance.